# Bake combined normal map in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

Exactly as the title says I got a texture which came with a normal map. When I try to bake out the combined end result for use with a real-time engine such as Unity I get as you see in the image below nothing as far as normal details are concerned.

I experimented, and when I plug my normal node into the displacement socket I get some results, but it looks horrible and is not the desired "normal map" effect. Any help on this would be great!

[image: Editor]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Normal Pass is generated from Face's Normal Vector

When you bake the normal map, you are converting the XYZ component of each surface's point normal vector into the correspective RGB color (according to the type of calculation: object, tangent..).

Is something that is not related with textures or shading, just geometry.

The result is correct, every point of your surface has a normal pointing out (local Z axis). That's where the blueish color is coming from (XY**Z**=>RG**B**).

[image]

What you probably are trying to bake is the **Color** of the Normal Map. Maybe you have combined several maps or some of them are a procedural textures converted with the bump node... what you need is to bake the Emission Pass (one of the fastes to bake you'll need just 1 sample, as with SSS Color, Glossy Color, Diffuse Color...) of an Emission shader with Strenght=1 that has the color you want in imput:

[image]

[image]

Here's an example of baking the Normal from procedural textures:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Anyway it would be cool to have a baking pass that automatically takes in account all the mix shaders nodes and returns the "final", weighted normal maps color. For now you'll have to unplug all of them and than combine them on your own.

Comment: Could you post the blend file in relation to the post you made I'm trying as you recommended, and still having some issues. My exact issue if your wondering is after I bake the "Emit" the bake result is black.

Comment: I'll build another one, that was already thrown away... You need the first or the second example?

Comment: The first example please where you use a normal map already made not the procedural one.

Comment: If it bakes black 1) Check to have an Emission shader as output 2) Check to have color in imput... so that't you have not accidentally baked (or trying to) on the texture where the color cames from and not on a new texture.

Comment: I THINK I follow you, but probably not I've been trying to grasp this normal map thing for days. http://i.imgur.com/D5oiHH1.png This is my result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28848/discussion-between-carlo-and-david-prentice).